# restructure a 2D numpy array based on matching column values

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working with a data set with ~30 million entries. Each entry has a timestamp, an ID, a Description, and a value. The overall numpy array looks something like:

```
[
[Time 1, ID 1, D 1_1, V 1_1],
[Time 1, ID 1, D 1_2, V 1_2],
...
[Time 2, ID 1, D 2_1, V 2_1],
[Time 2, ID 1, D 2_2, V 2_2],
...
[Time X, ID 2, D X_1, V X_1],
...
]
```

I would like to compress the array into the following format:

```
[
[Time 1, ID 1, D 1_1, V 1_1, D 1_2, V 1_2, ...],
[Time 2, ID 1, D 2_1, V 2_1, D 2_2, V 2_2, ...],
[Time X, ID 2, D X_1, V X_1, ...],
...
]
```

Each sub-array within the original array will be the same length and order, but the number of sub-arrays with the same time stamp is variable, as is the number of sub-arrays with the same ID. Is there a way of restructuring the array within a reasonable amount of time? The time, id, and description columns would be strings and the value column would be a float if that matters.

Ideally, I could end up with an array of dictionaries, i.e.

```
[{'time': Time1, 'ID': ID1, 'D1_1': V1_1, 'D1_2': V1_2, ...}...]
```

However, given the time my attempt at using dictionaries would take (>100 hours), I'm assuming dictionaries take too long to construct.

Comment: Do you always have the same number of Time/ID combinations?

Comment: What's the source?Structured array from `csv` via loadtxt/genfromtext  or pandas dataframe?

Comment: I do not. An ID could have a single time stamp associated with it, or >10,000 time stamps

Comment: Then you want some kind of `groupby`. While achievable with numpy, this would be easier to use pandas.

Comment: I'm loading the data from an SQL database using pandas.read.sql, with the SQL string being something like: SELECT time, id, description, value FROM table

Comment: Then why don't you reshape in SQL?

Comment: I'll checkout groupby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think with pandas you can easy achive that goal:

```
import pandas as pd

# your dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=your_np_array, columns=['Time', 'ID', 'Description', 'Value'])
# groupby time and ID, and aggregate the descriptions and values into lists
grouped = df.groupby(['Time', 'ID']).agg({'Description': list, 'Value': list})
# reset the index to get the time and ID as columns rather than indices
result = grouped.reset_index()
# convert the lists into separate columns
result['Description'] = result['Description'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))
result['Value'] = result['Value'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)))

# convert the result to a numpy array
my_new_numpy_array = result.to_numpy()
```

Comment: I'll probably keep the lists unpacked since I need the description associations, but this is pretty close to what I want. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to here that!